# Count the 4-digit integers that are multiple of 9

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, divisibility

I want to count the total number of 4-digit integers that are multiple of 9, without any zero digit.
I was wondering if the best strategy is to treat it as a count problem or just apply some properties from number theory.

Naive way is to solve $a+b+c+d = 9, 18, 27, 36$ with $1 \leq a, b, c, d \leq 9$ but I feel this takes much time with too many case works to consider.

Any way we could do faster?

Comment: Yes, there is a much faster option.  Pick $a,b,c$ as normal.  Now... *given such a selection* for the first three digits... how many choices do you have available for $d$ such that the resulting number is a multiple of nine?  Is that always the case for all such choices of $a,b,c$?  What can you then conclude?

Comment: Further hint... a number is a multiple of nine if and only if the sum of its digits is also a multiple of nine.

Comment: Well.  Let $a+b+c \equiv k\pmod 9$.  Then we must have $d\equiv -k \pmod 9$.  How many choices of that are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so you have determined that $abcd = 1000a + 100b + 10c + d$ is a multiple of $9$ if and only if $a+b+c+d$ is a multiple of $9$.

But now the trick is to realize that $a+b+c+d$ is a multiple of $9$ if and only if

$a+b+c+d \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ if and only if

$d\equiv -(a+b+c) \pmod 9$.

Now for any *possible* value $a+b+c$ may take, $-(a+b+c)\equiv$ to a specific digit $\pmod 9$ and there is exactly *1* digit between $1$ and $9$ that $d$ can take to be equivalent to $-(a+b+c)$.

(For example, if I just *randomly* pick $a= 5; b=7; c=2$ then $a+b+c\equiv 5\pmod 9$ and in order to have $572d$ divisible by $9$ we must have $a+b+c + d\equiv 5+d\equiv 0 \pmod 9$ or in other words $d \equiv -5 \equiv 4\pmod 9$.  We must have $d=4$.  It is the only choice and whatever choices we have for $a,b,c$ there will always bu exactly one choice for $d$).

So the number of four digit numbers equals

$(\text{number of choices for }a)\cdot(\text{number of choices for }b)\cdot(\text{number of choices for }c)\cdot(\text{number of choices for }d)=$

$9\cdot 9\cdot 9\cdot 1 = 9^3=729$

Answer (score 3):

If you have no restrictions to $1\leq a,b,c,d\leq 9$, there are $9^4$ such numbers. As JMoravitz and you already mentioned, we have $a+b+c+d\in9\mathbb Z$.
As JMoravitz already said, for every given $a,b,c\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$ there is exactly one choice for $d$, since there exists a unique $d$ with $9\mid a+b+c+d$ and $d\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$. Hence, the number of your 4-digit integers are...

Answer (score 0):

All multiples of $9$ are:
$$1008,1017,...,9999 \Rightarrow n=\frac{9999-1008}{9}+1=1000$$
Multiples with $1$ zero:
$$b=0 \ ( \text{ or } c=0 \text{ or } d=0), a+c+d=9,18,27; n_1=9^2\cdot 3$$
Multiples with $2$ zeroes:
$$b=c=0 \ (\text{ or } b=d=0 \text{ or } c=d=0), a+d=9,18; n_2=9\cdot 3 $$
Multiples with $3$ zeroes:
$$b=c=d=0, a=9; n_3=1$$
Hence, the final answer is:
$$n-n_1-n_2-n_3=1000-243-27-1=729.$$

Comment: This answer completely misses the point of the exercise.  Who cares how many multiples where zero was allowed has one two or three zeroes... that is extra work which is unnecessary.  Just say the answer is $9\times 9\times 9=729$ and be done with it.  All of this breaking into cases and practically brute force sets a horrible precedent for behavior which should not be repeated in larger problems.

Comment: If we were to ask how many 1000 digit numbers with no zeroes were multiples of nine... just think of all of the wasted page space your answer would use.  Meanwhile, using the elegant approach, you say "oh, just pick the first $999$ digits normally and then the choice for the last digit is forced so the answer is $9^{999}$" taking no space at all.

Comment: JMoravitz I had seen your comment and Jochen’s answer. Certainly your method is straightforward, mine is go around. I just offered an alternative method which btw also uses your method to count multiples with zeros.  I think knowing more methods is more useful. Peace.